# Can I stop gcc from allocating a local variable on the stack?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

I'm using gcc on x86-64 and declaring some local variables with the "register" modifier.  I would like to find a way to severely discourage the compiler from allocating and using stack space for these variables.  I'd like these variables to remain in registers as much as possible.  I'm mixing C/C++ code with inline assmebly.

The variables are simply working storage and don't need to be permanently stored and retrieved later, but yet I see my gcc -O2 code still tucking them into their local stack space from time to time.  I understand that their state will need to be preserved when I make C/C++ function calls from time to time, but can I do something to be certain that this preservation is severely discouraged?

Here is an example of what I'm doing.  This is a portion of an event-driven logic simulator for those who are wondering:

```
register __m128d VAL0, VAL1, diff0, diff1;
register __m128d *outputValPtr;
__m128d **cmfmLocs;
...
// all pointers are made to point to valid data
// cmfmLocs is a 0-terminated array of pointers with at least one entry

diff0 = outputValPtr[0];
diff1 = outputValPtr[1];
VAL0 = *(cmfmLocs[0]);
VAL1 = *(cmfmLocs[0]+1);

cfPin = 1;
do
{
  asm( "andpd %[src1], %[dest1]\n"
       "orpd  %[src2], %[dest2]\n" :
       [dest1] "=x" (VAL0),
       [dest2] "=x" (VAL1) :
       [src1]  "m" (*(cmfmLocs[cfPin])),
       [src2]  "m" (*(cmfmLocs[cfPin]+1)) );
  cfPin++;
} while ( cmfmLocs[cfPin] );

asm( "xorpd %[val0], %[diffBit0]\n"
     "xorpd %[val1], %[diffBit1]\n"
     "orpd  %[diffBit1], %[diffBit0]\n"
     "ptest %[diffBit0], %[diffBit0]\n"
     "jz dontSchedule\n"
     "movdqa %[val0],   (%[permStor])\n"
     "movdqa %[val1], 16(%[permStor])\n" :
     [diffBit0]  "=x" (diff0),
     [diffBit1]  "=x" (diff1),
     [memWrite1] "=m" (outputValPtr[0]),
     [memWrite2] "=m" (outputValPtr[1]) :
     [val0]      "x"  (VAL0),
     [val1]      "x"  (VAL1),
     [permStor]  "p"  (outputValPtr) );
SCHEDULE_GOTOS;
asm( "dontSchedule:\n" );
```

This code produced the following assembly with -O2:

```
2348: 48 8b 4b 50           mov    0x50(%rbx),%rcx
234c: ba 01 00 00 00        mov    $0x1,%edx
2351: 48 8b 41 08           mov    0x8(%rcx),%rax
2355: 0f 1f 00              nopl   (%rax)
2358: 83 c2 01              add    $0x1,%edx
235b: 66 0f 54 00           andpd  (%rax),%xmm0
235f: 66 0f 56 48 10        orpd   0x10(%rax),%xmm1
2364: 0f b7 c2              movzwl %dx,%eax
2367: 66 0f 29 4c 24 20     movapd %xmm1,0x20(%rsp)   # Why is this necessary?
236d: 66 0f 29 44 24 30     movapd %xmm0,0x30(%rsp)   # Why is this necessary?
2373: 48 8b 04 c1           mov    (%rcx,%rax,8),%rax
2377: 48 85 c0              test   %rax,%rax
237a: 75 dc                 jne    2358 <TEST_LABEL+0x10>
237c: 66 0f 57 d0           xorpd  %xmm0,%xmm2
2380: 66 0f 57 d9           xorpd  %xmm1,%xmm3
2384: 66 0f 56 d3           orpd   %xmm3,%xmm2
2388: 66 0f 38 17 d2        ptest  %xmm2,%xmm2
238d: 0f 84 cf e7 ff ff     je     b62 <dontSchedule>
2393: 66 41 0f 7f 07        movdqa %xmm0,(%r15)     # After storing here, xmm0/1 values
2398: 66 41 0f 7f 4f 10     movdqa %xmm1,0x10(%r15) #  are not needed anymore.
... # my C scheduler routine here ...
0000000000000b62 <dontSchedule>:
```

Comment: Have you tried using intrinsics?

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, I'm just making a WAG, but do you use VAL0 and VAL1 at some point after the second asm?  And for something to try, change the constraints for both diffBit* to "=&x".  Lastly, as the docs say "asm statements may not perform jumps into other asm statements."

Comment: Brett, I'll give them a try, see if/how the results change, and post an update.

Comment: David, no difference with the early-clobber modifier.  The code path diverges after this block (goes back into another loop iteration and a switch statement) but the value of VAL0/VAL1 is never needed again once it is stored in outValuePtr.  I have statements that theoretically "use" it, but really they're just clearing them or setting them to 1's (`xorpd %[VAL0], %[VAL0]` / `pcmpeqd %[VAL1], %[VAL1]`).  I've tried to be good about setting the constraints appropriately for these (output-only, `=x`).  I'll take another sweep through and make sure they are not inputs anywhere.

Comment: Also David, what's the recommended way to achieve the "jump" that I'm trying to do?  I saw something about `asm goto` for jumping to C labels.  I'd actually just like to jump to whichever location a C `break` statement would send me from the `switch` statement that I'm inside of.

Comment: When I switch to intrinsics, I find that it is using the "v" variants of the instructions, which are different encodings that what I chose.  (For example, I'm seeing the 3-parameter `vxorpd` instead of the 2-parameter `xorpd`.)  Does this have any performance impact?

Also, I still see the values getting tucked into the stack.  Not all of them, but some.  I'll take a long hard look at my program flow and make sure they're not used again in any situation.  With intrinsics, I'm finding it really hard to create an XMM register filled with all 0's or 1's without incurring a memory access.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it now!

I'm using the intrinsics, mainly because they are easy to use and don't require leaving the "C world".  The key for me was localizing the scope of my register variables.  That probably should have been obvious, but I got bogged down in the details.  My actual code now looks like this:

```
      ...
      case SimF_AND:
      {
        register __m128d VAL0 = *(cmfmLocs[0]);
        register __m128d VAL1 = *(cmfmLocs[0]+1);
        register __m128d diff0 = outputValPtr[0];
        register __m128d diff1 = outputValPtr[1];
        cfPin = 1;
        do
        {
          VAL0 = _mm_and_pd( VAL0, *(cmfmLocs[cfPin]) );
          VAL1 =  _mm_or_pd( VAL1, *(cmfmLocs[cfPin]+1) );
          cfPin++;
        } while ( cmfmLocs[cfPin] );
        diff0 = _mm_or_pd( _mm_xor_pd( VAL0, diff0 ), _mm_xor_pd( VAL1, diff1 ) ); \
        if ( !_mm_testz_pd( diff0, diff0 ) ) \
        { \
          outputValPtr[0] = VAL0; \
          outputValPtr[1] = VAL1; \
          outputValPtr[2] = _mm_xor_pd( VAL0, VAL0 ); \
          SCHEDULE_GOTOS; \
        }
      } // register variables go out of scope here
      break;
      ...
```

So now it is very easy for both me and the compiler to see that these variables are not referenced after outputValPtr is updated.  This produces assembly that does not reserve stack space for the locals so they don't generate any memory writes of their own anymore.

Thanks to all those who left responses.  You definitely lead me down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

I was told long ago that there are three classes of C compilers: Really dumb ones, which just don't care about the `register` keyword, dumb ones, which heed the keyword, and reserve a few regsters for this; and smart ones, which really do a much better job handling shuffling values around than just keeping a value in a fixed register.

If you use GCC's inline assembly, where the values reside should be (almost) transparent. You can force getting the arguments in specific registers by use of restrictions, and the compiler will make sure this gets respected.

Besides, "just working storage" isn't a good enough reason to use up a valuable register. Even in x86_64, which isn't register-starved. Writing parts of the program in assembly has a terrible cost in programmer time and portability, you better make very sure this is relevant performance wise (or the code can't be written portably in the first place).

Comment: Portability is not a concern here.  I need every cycle I can get.  This code is inside of a loop which executes not thousands, not even millions, but billions of times.  Every cycle I can cut will be noticeable to the end-user.  I don't mind giving up some control to the compiler, but when I see not just an instruction, but a memory write that I know isn't necessary, I have to try to squash it.